# How to join SQLITE tables using primary key in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, save

I have a database named 'assessment.db'

In this I have one table named 'Users' with this setup 
(firstName VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY)

and one named 'Books with this setup 
(pairBookName VARCHAR UNIQUE, activity1 VARCHAR, activity2 VARCHAR, activity3 VARCHAR)

The user enters their name, which is stored in the 'Users' table, I have that working perfectly at the moment. Now what I want to do is setup a checklist to track a user's progress through the activities.

So eg: 'Ryan' enters his name, then goes into Book1 and completes Activity1 and Activity2.

I'm trying to get my head around how to match up the Users table and Books table, it doesn't seem like a simple JOIN

I've looked through previous questions and can't seem to find anyone with the same database setup/problem.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, I would recommend that you get an introductory book (or website) on database design. Your schema has a number of problems:

1. How do you deal with 2 differant users named 'Jim'
2. How do you deal with 2 differant books named 'Introduction to database design'?
3. Does every book have exactly 3 activities? That is, none have 2 and none have 4?

With your specific question, this is a straightforward many-to-many relationship; a user may have many books and a book may have many users. This is dealt with using a 3rd table with the PK of users and the PK of books as its composite PK (niether of these should be a varchar!).

For your problem, this may be the table where you store the activities.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for an intermediate join table that allows a many-to-many relationship to exist.  I might suggest something like this for a table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE User
(
    UniqueID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL Primary Key default newid(),
    FirstName nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    etc..
)

CREATE TABLE Book
(
    UniqueID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL Primary Key default newid(),
     Title nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
     etc..
)

CREATE TABLE Activity
(
    UniqueID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL Primary Key default newid(),
    Description nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    etc...
)

CREATE TABLE UserActivity
(
    UserID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    BookID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    ActivityID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_UserActivity PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        UserID ASC,
        BookID ASC,
        ActivityID ASC
    )
)
```

This way, many users can have many activities for many books.  Best practices for database design suggest that you don't use FirstName as the primary key since many people could have the same first name.  You'll want something a little more unique like an int field or a uniqueidentifier.

Book and Activity are similar - they store the different books ("Book 1", "Book 2") and the different types of activities that can be performed ("Completes Activity 1", "Completes Activity 2").

Every time a user finishes an activity for a book, a record gets inserted into UserActivity which describes the User, the Book, and the Activity that was performed.

Though this certainly may seem like overkill at this point, you will not regret it if you decide to add onto the functionality at some point down the road - like adding a new type of activity, or a new book that doesn't have all the same types of activities as other books.  A well-designed database should make it easy to add new stuff to your software.  Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the input, I was going about this all the wrong way it seems.

I ended up using code to create tables on the fly when a username is entered:

```
   var form = document.getElementById("userName");
   localStorage.name = form.elements.firstName.value;
   var user = localStorage.name;

   db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+user+"(bookName TEXT, activity1 TEXT, activity2 TEXT, activity3 TEXT, activity4 TEXT, activity5 TEXT, activity6 TEXT, activity7 TEXT, activity8 TEXT, activity9 TEXT)");
```

This way I can keep the user in localStorage.name and call it later to update progress.